# How does doctrine entity manager flush() method works?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

In the [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#starting-with-the-product) there is this code:

```
<?php
// update_product.php <id> <new-name>
require_once "bootstrap.php";

$id = $argv[1];
$newName = $argv[2];

$product = $entityManager->find('Product', $id);

if ($product === null) {
    echo "Product $id does not exist.\n";
    exit(1);
}

$product->setName($newName);

$entityManager->flush();
```

What I don't understand is the last part, where, after setting the product name with `$product->setName()`, the `$entityManager->flush()` method is called:

```
$product->setName($newName);
$entityManager->flush();
```

It seems to me that there is no connection between the `$product` variable and the `$entityManager` variable, except for the fact that `$product` should contain the response from the `$entityManager->find()` method.

How is it possible that `$entityManager->flush()` can read values set by `$product->setName()`?

Comment: There should be a line of code there to persist:
$product->setName($newName);
$entityManager->persist($product);
$entityManager->flush();

Comment: @gvk, no, it should not, persist is only used when the entity is not yet managed by Doctrine, like after ``$product = new Product();``

Comment: Yep - looks like I was mistaken :-(

Comment: @Aerendit: You've asked a great question, but I think you should change the title of your question to something more common like "How flush() mechanism works" or something similar to make the question even more usefull for community.

Comment: It is "unit of work" pattern. Doctrine has a registry that contains all managed objects. When you call $entityManager->find('Product', $id), founded object is automatically added to that invisible registry. When you calling flush(), it detects which objects were changed and performs saving these objects to a database.

Answer (score 16):

It's a `ORM` magic :)

But if seriously, when you fetch your data using `Doctrine`, it added to your objects a lot of metadata. You can look at these fields by yourself just `var_dump()` an object.

When you make `flush()`, `Doctrine` checks all the fields of all fetched data and make a transaction to the database.

When you initialize a new object, it doesn't have any `Doctrine` metadata, so you have to call one more method `persist()` to add it.

Also you can just look at the [source code](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#32-751) of `EntityManager` to better understand how it works — `Doctrine` is an opensource project.

Comment: The OP actually missed the persist part - there is no magic :-)

Comment: No, I think everything is OK, please look at my last part of the answer.

Comment: `flush` does not always make a transaction in the database; I know, I ran tests on it. If `flush` is within `beginTransaction`, no SQL query will actually be run until that transaction's object scope runs `commit`. If there's any inner-scope `beginTransaction` calls, anything run from those scopes will be simply "queued" for saving when the top-level scope is committed.

Answer (score 10):

> Doctrine uses the **Identity Map** pattern to track objects. Whenever you
>   fetch an object from the database, Doctrine will keep a reference to
>   this object inside its **UnitOfWork**. The array holding all the entity
>   references is two-levels deep and has the keys “root entity name” and
>   “id”. Since Doctrine allows composite keys the id is a sorted,
>   serialized version of all the key columns.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork.html

And you might ask how it can read/write the values to the entity, because, well, they are protected (they should if you are following the user guide)!

It's simple, Doctrine uses [reflection](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.reflection.php).

Interesting method from the UnityOfWork which computes if there are any changes to the entities: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L560